# MySQL / PHP transaction behavior

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

Given:

```
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
mysql_query("UPDATE foo = 'bar'");
die();
```

`die()` stops the transaction before I can `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. Looking at my tables, it appears that the update doesn't take place, but if I run queries later in another script, are they still part of that initial transaction? Is the transaction still 'open' until I `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`?

Answer (score 4):

If die kills the connection to mysql then yes, the transaction is closed. If you're just leaving the transaction hanging though you're going to get in trouble.

I would recommend making sure that the transaction and the commit are in the same mysql_query if at all humanly possible to ensure that it actually happens.

Comment: According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php:

"Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution."

Since die() ends the script's execution, I would assume that means that the database connection is closed?

Comment: And unfortunately, I'm not using mysqli, so I can't do multiple queries at once.

Comment: That's correct, I was just wondering if you were really going to be completely faithful about always die()ing after your transaction was opened. I mean, how often are you really going to die() in a real-life scenario? That's why I mentioned that you probably shouldn't rely on die() to close a transaction for you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your serialization level. If a transaction is neither committed or rolled back, it should time out after a while and rolled back in the DB. But until then it is an unfinished transaction which might cause inconsistent selects in other non serializable transactions. Dependent on it's [level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29):

- read uncommitted: you can read the uncommitted, unfinished values until rollback
- repeatable read (mysql default): you won't read uncommitted values, but as ranges are not locked, a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE 18 < age AND age < 24 is not guaranteed to return consistent values until rollback