# What happens to a mysqli transaction when the connection is closed without a commit or rollback?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Related questions, but not quite what I'd like to know, as I'm curious about the specific behavior of the PHP `mysqli` lib/functions:

- [What happens when a connection is closed mid-transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59408397/what-happens-when-a-connection-is-closed-mid-transaction)
- [What happens to an uncommitted transaction when the connection is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539564/what-happens-to-an-uncommitted-transaction-when-the-connection-is-closed)

Suppose I have some code like so (disregarding whether its good or bad practice):

```php
# ... some code

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'widget-manager', 'secret-widgets', 'widgets');
$conn->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);
if (false) {
    $sql = "UPDATE widgets SET widget_num = 1 WHERE widget_id = 5";
    $res = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($res) {
        $conn->commit();
    } else {
        $conn->rollback();
    }
}
$conn->close();

# ... some more code
```

The `if` which contains the commits and rollbacks would be skipped and the `mysqli` connection would be closed after the transaction was started, but before a commit or rollback was invoked.

Would the transaction also be immediately destroyed/ended/whatever-the-proper-term, or would it remain and possibly block other queries from other services?

Comment: Please share more details. What's the scenario you want to cover? If your transaction contains no update or insert statements, what should be the problem?

Comment: I want to know if the transaction would be left open on the DB side as it hadn't been explicitly committed or rolled back, and potentially block other queries.

Comment: Your code is weird. It only `begin_transaction()` once, but then does a `commit()` for each individual query. Why use transactions here at all?

Comment: Code has been edited to be somewhat more straightfoward, but this is just an example to highlight the possible situation @KIKOSoftware, not something we actually would have in production.

Comment: If the connection gets closed, why should the transaction be kept open?

Comment: That is precisely what I wanted to know, I suspected it would be closed, but found nothing explicitly saying so, hence me asking this question. If you would like to post an answer of "It would be automatically closed/commited upon the connection closing" @NicoHaase I would be happy to mark it as accepted.

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495989/mysql-and-php-pdo-what-happens-to-an-uncommited-transaction-if-connection-clos?

Comment: Have a look in the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html), at the bottom of this page: _"Rolling back can be a slow operation that may occur implicitly without the user having explicitly asked for it (for example, when an error occurs)."_ and _"If a SELECT statement within a transaction calls a stored function, and a statement within the stored function fails, that statement rolls back. "_. Not a complete answer, I admit. It seems a rollback will be performed, in the end, when no commit was issued.

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087377/mysql-php-transaction-behavior

Comment: Otherwise, why not check for this on your own? According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598373/display-open-transactions-in-mysql, you can list the open transactions

Comment: So the consensus is that `mysqli` does not introduce any different behavior than a PDO-originating connection/query or an actual raw MySQL connection/query then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `begin_transaction()` or set the `autocommit` value to 0 then you are effectively telling MySQL server *"don't commit the data until I explicitly tell you to"*. When you write code that never calls commit then the data on the server will never be committed.

When you call `mysqli::close()` or **if the PHP script ends**, then mysqlnd (or libmysql) will send `COM_QUIT` command to the server. The server will then close the session and discard any data related to it, including open transactions, locks, or prepared statement handles. The MySQL server should also honour the [`wait_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) setting in case the PHP script crashes and the command is never sent.

One thing that would be specific to mysqli is persistent connections. These connection are reused between PHP executions. They are commonly regarded as a good way to shoot yourself in the foot, which is why mysqli has some logic to help with that. You can use the INI setting called `rollback_on_cached_plink` to instruct mysqli to clean up the persistent connection whenever the script ends by issuing a rollback command.

Answer (score 3):

If the client disconnects, the MySQL Server cleans up the session. This rolls back any uncommitted transaction, releases row locks and table locks, removes temporary tables and session variables, etc.

It makes no difference which client interface is used (mysqli vs. PDO vs. Java vs. anything).